# Offline authentication flow in Progressive web app

Tags: progressive-web-apps, openid-connect, offline-caching

What is the best approach for authentication flow in PWA when its offline. I am using OIDC client js for online authentication flow.

Answer (score 2):

The Authorization Server sits alongside your APIs so I would treat both the same:

- If the device is offline you cannot call your APIs so you have to use data that is cached locally - such as that for the last rendered view
- If the device is offline you also cannot perform user authentication or token refresh operations

Nothing about OIDC behaviour would change - you just need a design pattern for API access, which does not really depend on the technology you are using:

- MyView uses a MyApiClient
- When online, MyApiClient initiates OAuth related calls if there is no token yet, then adds a token to the Authorization header and calls MyApi
- When offline, MyApiClient looks in a local cache instead and displays cached data if it can, while also informing the user they are offline